# Use ftell to find the file size

Tags: c, ftell

```
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); 
  size = ftell(f);
```

If ftell(f) tells us the current file position, the size here should be the offset from the end of the file to the beginning. Why is the size not ftell(f)+1? Should not ftell(f) only give us the position of the end of the file?

Comment: The file position indicator is setting 1-past the last char, meaning `ftell` will report the number of character from the start to the indicator which is the bytes in `f` not `f+1`.

Comment: `"The ftell() function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream."` It is the offset from the beginning, `f` doesn't change.

Comment: " the size here should be the offset from the end of the file to the beginning" --> not necessarily if the file is a _text_ file.

Comment: File positions are 0-based.

Comment: When you seek to the end, you should imagine that your purpose is to append data to the end of the file. You should not imagine that your purpose is to read the last character. So `SEEK_END` is the location **after** the last character in the file. Note that on Microsoft systems, `SEEK_END` is not a good idea unless you opened the file file in binary mode, e.g. `fopen(filename, "rb")`.

Comment: @user3386109 *`SEEK_END` is not a good idea unless you opened the file file in binary mode*  Which, pedantically-speaking, is [literally undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268).

Comment: @AndrewHenle The C standard does not provide a `fsize(FILE *fp)` function. **It should, but it doesn't.** And I suspect that's because the standards committee couldn't even agree on the meaning of the phrase *"file size"*. Which leaves programmers to find practical solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File positions are like the cursor in a text entry widget: they are *in between* the bytes of the file.  This is maybe easiest to understand if I draw a picture:

[image: Depiction of a file that is four characters long. There are five boxes in a row; from left to right, they contain the letters "a", "b", "c", and "d", and the fifth one has its area X-ed out. Below the boxes, aligned with the vertical lines to the left of and in between the boxes, are the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.]

This is a hypothetical file.  It contains four characters: <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, and <kbd>d</kbd>.  Each character gets a little box to itself, which we call a "byte".  (This file is ASCII.)  The fifth box has been crossed out because it's not part of the file yet, but but if you appended a fifth character to the file it would spring into existence.

The valid file positions in this file are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.  There are five of them, not four; they correspond to the vertical lines before, after, and in between the boxes.  When you open the file (assuming you don't use `"a"`), you start out on position 0, the line before the first byte in the file.  When you seek to the end, you arrive at position 4, the line after the last byte in the file.  Because we start counting from zero, this is also the number of bytes in the file.  (This is one of the several reasons *why* we start counting from zero, rather than one.)

I am obliged to warn you that there are several reasons why

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long int nbytes = ftell(fp);
```

might not give you the number you actually want, depending on what you mean by "file size" and on the contents of the file.  In no particular order:

- On Windows, if you open a file in text mode, the numbers you get from `ftell` on that file are *not* byte offsets from the beginning of the file; they are more like `fgetpos` cookies, that can only be used in a subsequent call to `fseek`.  If you need to seek around in a text file on Windows you may be better off opening the file in binary mode and dealing with both DOS and Unix line endings yourself — this is actually my recommendation for production code in general, because it's perfectly possible to have a file with DOS line endings on a Unix system, or vice versa.
- On systems where `long int` is 32 bits, files can easily be bigger than that, in which case `ftell` will fail, return −1 and set `errno` to `EOVERFLOW`.  POSIX.1-2001-compliant systems provide a function called [`ftello`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseeko.3.html) that returns an `off_t` quantity that can represent larger file sizes, provided you put `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` at the very top of all your source files (before any `#include`s).  I don't know what the Windows equivalent is.
- If your file contains characters that are beyond ASCII, then the number of *bytes* in the file is very likely to be different from the number of *characters* in the file.  (For instance, if the file is encoded in UTF-8, the character <kbd>啡</kbd> will take up three bytes, <kbd>Ä</kbd> will take up either two or three bytes depending on whether it's "composed", and <kbd>జ్ఞా</kbd> will take up *twelve* bytes because, despite being a single [grapheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme), it's a string of four Unicode code points.) `ftell(o)` will still tell you the correct number to pass to `malloc`, if your goal is to read the entire file into memory, but iterating over "characters" will not be so simple as `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`.
- If you are using C's "wide streams" and "wide characters", then, just like text streams on Windows, the numbers you get from `ftell` on that file are not byte offsets and may not be useful for anything other than subsequent calls to `fseek`.  But wide streams and characters are a bad design anyway; you're actually more likely to be able to handle all the world's languages correctly if you stick to processing UTF-8 by hand in narrow streams and characters.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why `fseek()`/`ftell()` is taught as a generic way to get the size of a file.  It only works because an implementation defines it to work.  POSIX does, for one.  Windows does, also, for binary streams - but not for text streams.

It's wrong to not add a caveat or warning to, "This is how you get the number of bytes in a file."  Because when a programmer first gets on a system that doesn't define `fseek()`/`ftell()` as byte offsets, they're going to have problems.  I've seen it.

"But I was told this is how you can always do it."

"Well, no.  Whoever taught you was wrong."

Because it is impossible to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file in strictly-conforming C code.

For a binary stream, **7.21.9.2  The `fseek` function**, paragraph 3 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the
>   beginning of the file,  is  obtained  by  adding `offset` to  the 
>   position  specified  by `whence`. The  specified position is the
>   beginning of the file if `whence` is `SEEK_SET`, the current value of
>   the file position indicator if SEEK_CUR , or end-of-file if
>   `SEEK_END`. **A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek`
>   calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.**

Footnote 268 specifically states:

> Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with
>   `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  **has undefined behavior for a binary
>   stream** (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any
>   stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in
>   the initial shift state.

So you can't seek the the end of a binary stream to get a file's size in bytes.

And for a text stream, **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function**, paragraph 2 states:

> The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position
>   indicator for the stream pointed  to  by `stream`. For  a  binary 
>   stream,  the  value  is  the  number  of  characters  from the
>   beginning of the file.  **For a text stream, its file position
>   indicator contains unspecified information**, usable by the `fseek`
>   function for returning the file position indicator for the stream  to 
>   its  position  at  the  time  of  the `ftell` call;  **the  difference
>   between  two  such return values is not necessarily a meaningful
>   measure of the number of characters written or read**.

So you can't use `ftell()` on a text stream to get a byte count.

The only strictly-conformant approach that I'm aware of to get the number of bytes in a file is to read them one-by-one with `fgetc()` and count them.

Comment: You're not _wrong_ here, but I think the possibility of `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)` not being usable on a binary stream is very nearly as irrelevant nowadays as the possibility that signed integers might not be twos-complement. Much more important to warn people about the subsequent `ftell` not giving the right number for _text_ streams, which is still a live issue if only because of Windows, and about files potentially being bigger than `long int` can represent. And even after all that, this technique _is_ still a tiny bit more portable than `fileno` and `fstat`.

Comment: @zwol  Umm, these are not exactly rare:  https://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+mainframe+jobs

Comment: So if I only input binary files, I guess using fseek and ftell to figure out the file size should be okay?

Comment: @OptatootatpO *So if I only input binary files, I guess using fseek and ftell to figure out the file size should be okay?* On Windows and POSIX system, yes.  And as long as the file size fits into the `long` value that `ftell()` returns.