# Printing all phrases in a file with C program

Tags: c, file, file-io, c-strings, string.h

I need to print all phrases from a file (phrases can end in '.', '?' or '!')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* read_file(char *name) {
    FILE *file;
    char *text;
    long num_bytes;

    file = fopen(name, "r");

    if(!file) {
        printf("File could not be opened!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    num_bytes = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    text = (char*) malloc(num_bytes * sizeof(char));
    fread(text, 1, num_bytes, file);
    
    fclose(file);

    return text;
}
```

I have this piece of code that kind of works but if my file as the following text: "My name is Maria. I'm 19." the second phrase is printed with a ' ' in the beggining.
Can someone please help finding a way to ignore those spaces? Thank you

Comment: `char *line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(text));` doesn't do what you think. `text` is a pointer, so `sizeof(text)` returns the size of the pointer (probably 8, but depends on your architecture), not the size of the memory block it points to.

Comment: Oh yes @yano it should be char ```*line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(text));```, but still that's not the problem

Comment: Replace `printf("File could not be opened!");` with `perror(name);`.  Error messages belong on stderr and should provide a reason.

Comment: The method of fseeking to determine the file size is fundamentally broken.  Just read the data until you cannot read anymore.  In some instances, you do need the file size (this is very rare).  In those cases, you'll want to use a platform specific method for finding the size (eg `stat`)

Comment: _"I need to print all phrases from a file I have this piece of code that kind of works"_...   It appears you edited out the code you had originally included.  Without this code all of the answers, comments and interaction no longer make sense.  May I suggest that you add your code back into the post.  Please comment when you do that.

Comment: the question is missing the code that the question is asking for help on.

Answer (score 3):

To start, you have several problems that will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). In

```
char *line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(text));
```

`sizeof (text)` is the size of a pointer (`char *`), not the length of the buffer it points to.

`sizeof (char *)` depends on your system, but is very likely to be `8` (go ahead and test this: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (char *));`, if you are curious), which means `line` can hold a string of *length* `7` (plus the null-terminating byte).

Long sentences will easily overflow this buffer, leading to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

*(Aside: [do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965) in C.)*

Additionally, `strlen(text)` may not work properly as `text` may not include the null-terminating byte (`'\0'`). `fread` works with raw bytes, and does not understand the concept of a [*null-terminated string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) - files do not have to be null-terminated, and `fread` will not null-terminate buffers for you.

You should allocate one additional byte to in the `read_file` function

```
text = malloc(num_bytes + 1);
text[num_bytes] = 0;
```

and place the null-terminating byte there.

*(Aside: `sizeof (char)` is **guaranteed** to be `1`.)*

Note that `ftell` to determine the length of a file [should not be relied upon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122325/2505965).

---

[`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) from `<ctype.h>` can be used to determine if the current character is whitespace. Its argument should be cast to `unsigned char`. Note this will include characters such as `'\t'` and `'\n'`. Use simple comparison if you only care about spaces (`text[i + 1] == ' '`).

A loop can be used to consume the trailing whitespace after matching a delimiter.

Make sure to null-terminate `line` before printing it, as `%s` expects a *string*.

Use `%u` to print an `unsigned int`.

Do not forget to `free` your dynamically allocated memory when you are done with it. Additionally, heavily consider checking any library function that can *fail* has not done so.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pdie(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char *read_file(char *name) {
    FILE *file = fopen(name, "r");

    if (!file)
        pdie(name);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long num_bytes = ftell(file);

    if (-1 == num_bytes)
        pdie(name);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *text = malloc(num_bytes + 1);

    if (!text)
        pdie("malloc");

    if (-1 == num_bytes)
        pdie(name);

    text[num_bytes] = 0;

    if (fread(text, 1, num_bytes, file) != num_bytes)
        pdie(name);

    fclose(file);

    return text;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s TEXT_FILE\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *text = read_file(argv[1]);
    unsigned int count = 0;

    size_t length = strlen(text);
    size_t index = 0;
    char *line = malloc(length + 1);

    if (!line)
        pdie("malloc");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        line[index++] = text[i];

        if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!') {
            line[index] = '\0';
            index = 0;

            printf("[%u] <<%s>>\n", ++count, line);

            while (isspace((unsigned char) text[i + 1]))
                i++;
        }
    }

    free(text);
    free(line);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Input file:

```
My name is Maria. I'm 19. Hello world! How are you?
```

`stdout`:

```
[1] <<My name is Maria.>>
[2] <<I'm 19.>>
[3] <<Hello world!>>
[4] <<How are you?>>
```

Comment: Pedantic: "Its argument should be cast to unsigned char" --> to work well with nearly non-existent non 2's compliment as well as 2's complement, access the string via `unsigned char *`:  `isspace((unsigned char) text[i + 1])` --> `isspace(((unsigned char *) text)[i + 1])`.  Makes a difference when `char` is _signed_ and non 2's compliment.  This issue likely irrelevant with next C release which may mandate 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for a whitespace character by comparing the char in question to ' '.

```
if(text[i] == ' ')
    // text[i] is whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, advance to the next non-whitespace character when you find the end of the sentence.  You also need to make sure you've `malloc`d enough memory for the current phrase:

```
#include <ctype.h>  // for isspace
... 

size_t textLength = strlen(text);
// malloc based on the text length here, plus 1 for the NUL terminator.
// sizeof(text) gives you the size of the pointer, not the size of the
// memory block it points to.
char *line = malloc(textLength+1);

for(size_t i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
    line[index] = text[i];
    index++;
    if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!') {
        count++;
        printf("[%d] %s\n", count, line);
        memset(line, 0, index + 1);
        index = 0;
        // advance to the next non-whitespace char
        do
        {
            // advance to the next char (we know the current char is not a space)
            i++;
        // keep advancing i while the next char is in range of the
        // text and the next char is a space.
        }while (i+1 < textLength && isspace(text[i+1]) != 0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] My name is Maria.
[2] I'm 19.
```

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/xMh93K737)

There's also [no need to cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)