# How do I find the source of the pointer error

Tags: c, file, pointers, error-handling, malloc

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "splitter.h"

#define FOUR_K 4096

SplitResult split_join(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    SplitResult rs = E_NO_ACTION;

    if (argc < 7) 
    {
        return rs;
    }

    char* spiltOrJoin = argv[1];
    char* isSpiltOrJoin = spiltOrJoin;

    if (strcmp(isSpiltOrJoin, "-s") != 0 && strcmp(isSpiltOrJoin, "-j") != 0) 
    {
        return rs;
    }

    if (strcmp(isSpiltOrJoin, "-s") == 0) 
    {
        int smallChunkSize = atoi(argv[2]);

        const char* inputFileName = argv[6];
        const char* outputFilePrefix = argv[4];

        FILE* input = fopen(inputFileName, "rb");
        if (input != NULL) 
        {
            fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
            long fileSize = ftell(input);
            fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);

            int numChunks = (fileSize + smallChunkSize - 1) / smallChunkSize;

            char buffer[FOUR_K];

            int numOfPiecesOfChunk = smallChunkSize / sizeof(buffer);

            for (int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) 
            {
                char outputFileName[256];
                snprintf(outputFileName, sizeof(outputFileName), "%s%s%d", outputFilePrefix, "000", i + 1);
                FILE* output = fopen(outputFileName, "wb");

                if (output == NULL)
                {
                    rs = E_BAD_DESTINATION;
                    fclose(input);
                    return rs;
                }

                char* chunkBuffer = (char*)malloc(FOUR_K);

                if (chunkBuffer == NULL)
                {
                    rs = E_NO_MEMORY;
                    fclose(input);
                    fclose(output);
                    return rs;
                }

                if (numOfPiecesOfChunk > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < numOfPiecesOfChunk; j++)
                    {
                        size_t bytesRead = fread(chunkBuffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), input);
                        fwrite(chunkBuffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                    }

                    int remainingBytesOfChunk = smallChunkSize - (sizeof(chunkBuffer) * numOfPiecesOfChunk);
                    size_t bytesRead = fread(chunkBuffer, 1, remainingBytesOfChunk, input);
                    fwrite(chunkBuffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                }
                else
                {
                    size_t bytesRead = fread(chunkBuffer, 1, smallChunkSize, input);
                    fwrite(chunkBuffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                }

                fclose(output); //Problem statement

                FILE* checkInput = fopen(outputFileName, "rb");

                if (checkInput == NULL)
                {
                    rs = E_BAD_DESTINATION;
                    free(chunkBuffer);
                    fclose(input);
                    return rs;
                }

                fseek(checkInput, 0, SEEK_END);
                long fileSize = ftell(checkInput);
                fseek(checkInput, 0, SEEK_SET);

                if (fileSize <= 0)
                {
                    rs = E_SMALL_SIZE;
                    free(chunkBuffer);
                    fclose(input);
                    fclose(checkInput);
                    return rs;
                }

                fclose(checkInput);

                free(chunkBuffer);
            }

            fclose(input);
            rs = E_SPLIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else 
        {
            rs = E_BAD_SOURCE;
            return rs;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        char* outputFile = argv[3];
        char* title = outputFile;
        int numOfFiles = argc - 5;
        FILE* output = fopen(title, "wb");

        if (output != NULL) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) 
            {
                FILE* chunkFile = fopen(argv[i + 5], "rb");

                if (chunkFile == NULL) 
                {
                    rs = E_BAD_SOURCE;
                    return rs;
                }

                fseek(chunkFile, 0, SEEK_END);
                long fileSize = ftell(chunkFile);
                int sizeOfFile = (int)fileSize;
                fseek(chunkFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

                int numOfFilePieces = 0;

                char* buffer = (char*)malloc(FOUR_K);

                if (buffer == NULL)
                {
                    rs = E_NO_MEMORY;
                    fclose(chunkFile);
                    fclose(output);
                    return rs;
                }

                if (sizeOfFile > sizeof(buffer)) 
                {
                    numOfFilePieces = sizeOfFile / sizeof(buffer);
                }

                if (chunkFile != NULL) {
                    if (numOfFilePieces > 0) 
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numOfFilePieces; i++) 
                        {
                            size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), chunkFile);
                            fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                        }

                        int remainingBytesOfChunk = sizeOfFile - (sizeof(buffer) * numOfFilePieces);
                        size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, remainingBytesOfChunk, chunkFile);
                        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeOfFile, chunkFile);
                        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, output);
                    }

                    fclose(chunkFile);
                }

                free(buffer);
            }

            rs = E_JOIN_SUCCESS;

            fclose(output);
        }
        else if (output == NULL) 
        {
            rs = E_BAD_DESTINATION;
            return rs;
        }
    }

    return rs;
}
```

I'm trying to write a C program that separates a file into smaller files and then joins smaller files into bigger ones. When I try and run the program, I get a munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error that caused the line fclose(output)(indicated by problem statement). Why is this happening?

At first I thought that the malloc was causing issues with some variables having the same name but it wasn't.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, probably 8, not the size of the allocation it points to. Try replacing everywhere you use that with `FOUR_K`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja `buffer` is a `char[FOUR_K]` so `sizeof(buffer)` is the same as `FOUR_K`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, perhaps I confused it with `char* chunkBuffer = (char*)malloc(FOUR_K);` So this `int remainingBytesOfChunk = smallChunkSize - (sizeof(chunkBuffer) * numOfPiecesOfChunk);` is probably incorrect. That's likely the line I originally intended to copy and instead grabbed the one a few lines above it.

Comment: As for how to find the source of memory corruption AddressSanitizer often works wonders.

Comment: see e.g. https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/ for compiler options related to warnings and sanitizers

Comment: @TedLyngmo Looked again and found `char* buffer = (char*)malloc(FOUR_K);` and several uses of `sizeof(buffer)` in the bottom half of the code. This code would be better with no `malloc` at all.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, I didn't get that far :-)

Comment: @user12645705  If you want debugging help, you need to provide us with code that we can compile. Please read about how to create a [mre].

Comment: `split_join` is an absurdly long function (196 lines!), and ironically you should split it up into a few smaller functions - which will help with debugging, as you can focus on making sure each individual function works as expected in isolation. Additionally note that using `ftell` to determine the the "size" of a file is unwise - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122325/2505965). Use platform specific system calls (e.g., [`stat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The "split" part of this code is 100 lines long (without comments). It's no wonder there's an invisible bug (pointed out by @RetiredNinja). Too much code and too many variables! Why does `buffer[FOUR_K]` sit unused while another buffer (`chunkBuffer`) is allocated off the heap? This makes no sense.

Below is an untested rewrite of the "split" part of the function. The "join" part is silly when `cat` would do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stat.h> // new
#include "splitter.h"

SplitResult splitOne( FILE *ifp, size_t smallChunkSize, int idx, char *prefix ) {
    FILE *ofp = NULL;
    size_t want = smallChunkSize; // size of each output file

    char ofn[256];
    snprintf( ofn, sizeof(ofn), "%s%06d", prefix, idx );
    if( ( ofp = fopen( ofn, "wb" ) ) == NULL ) // start a new file
        return E_BAD_DESTINATION;

    while( want ) { // while batch incomplete
        char buf[FOUR_K];

        // the minimum of buffer size or remaining in batch
        size_t maxToRead = min( sizeof buf, want );
        size_t got = fread( buf, 1, maxToRead, ifp );
        // Should test for unexpected EOF
        // N.B. Last read of source likely to be < expected.

        fwrite( buf, 1, got, ofp ); // obvious

        want -= got; // reduce count remaining for this batch
    }
    fclose( ofp );

    return E_SPLIT_SUCCESS;
}

SplitResult split( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int smallChunkSize = atoi(argv[2]);
    char *ifn = argv[6];
    char *prefix = argv[4];

    if ( ( ifp = fopen( ifn, "rb" ) ) == NULL)
        return E_BAD_SOURCE;

    // Correct way to get a file's byte count
    struct stat finfo;
    if( fstat( fileno( ifp ), &finfo ) != 0 ) {
        fclose( ifp );
        return E_BAD_SOURCE;
    }

    int i = 1; // for unique output filenames
    size_t remain = finfo.st_size; // remain in source file
    SplitResult rs = E_NO_ACTION; // a default initial value

    while( remain // while source file not exhausted
    && ( rs = splitOne( ifp, smallChunkSize, i++, prefix ) ) == E_SPLIT_SUCCESS ) // want a batch of this size
        remain -= smallChunkSize; // shrink remaining in source file

    fclose( ifp );

    return rs;
}

SplitResult split_join( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if (argc < 7)
        return E_NO_ACTION;

    if( strcmp( split_join, "-s" ) == 0 ) return split( argc, argv );

    if( strcmp( split_join, "-j" ) == 0 ) return join( argc, argv ); // not done

    return E_NO_ACTION;
}
```

Each function in the call stack does its *thing* in preparation for calling the next function. Don't try to do everything in one monolith function.

(Please note: no dynamic allocation that can fail.)